# How to sort a dataset in descending order based on number of users given a group of multiple columns?

Tags: r

I am having difficulty figuring out how to sort a dataset based on certain categories or columns and have it return the number of users in a "top ten" list.

Essentially I wanted to group by the month aka `month_of_day`, then by the type of user aka `member_casual`, to find which location has the most users aka `start_station_name` with `users`

```
For example,

1. Jan, Casual, Jefferson Station, 500 users
2. Jan, Casual, Bradley Station, 450 users
...
11. Jan, Member, Jefferson Station, 468 Users
...
n. Nov, Member, Harrison Station, 300 Users.
```

Essentially showing going through January - December, while comparing Casual vs Member and showing the Station Name with the amount of users.

I was testing to see if I use the `group_by()` function to first group the columns and then do `Sort(desc()) or Arrange(desc())` function to show the top ten.

But I am struggling because it would either show the top ten throughout the data set, or show every single entry.

I was thinking to create two separate datasets,

one for Casual and one for Members

For example with Casual

```
location_2022_c = annual_2022_v2 %>% 
  filter(member_casual == "casual") %>% 
  group_by(month_of_day, start_station_name) %>% 
  summarize(users = n())
```

and then merge them together later.

But I am just completely lost of how to order them in general.

I searched through the internet, but I don't think the solution I am seeking is out there. This is because I want to see if I can get a top ten locations given both `month_of_day` and `member_casual` rather than just seeing the most value in `users`.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier to help if you used dput(dataframe) to provide some real sample data but if I am understanding the requirement you can group and then use `slice_max(n=10, Users)` similar to below with this fake data. (Note: This will give the top 10 places by user count for each Month and Category)

```
library(dplyr)

data <- data.frame(
  Month = sample(c("Jan","Nov", "Feb", "March"), 10000, replace = T),
  Cat = sample(c("Casual", "Full"), 10000, replace = T),
  Place = sample(letters, 10000, replace = T),
  Users = sample(c(100:500), 10000, replace = T))

TopList <- data %>% group_by(Month, Cat, Place) %>% summarize(Users = sum(Users)) %>%
  slice_max(n=10, Users)
```

The summarize is not necessary unless you need to aggregate on location, it's enough to group and slice on User.

Comment: Apologies for not posting a real sample data. Wasn't aware of commands such as dput(). Would test your suggestion and will update you.

Comment: Hello Alex. This worked perfectly. Thank you so much. In the future, I will provide a sample data set you have suggested. Slice_max has worked its wonders.